# img tag displaying img from folder but background-image not?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using the below code to pull through user uploads into a portfolio. It's working great however one image (out of a list of many) is showing blank - yet displays on the next page, using the same path, but within a conventional `<img />` tag.

```
<?php
    $files= glob('./uploads/users/'. $item->user_id .'/'.$item->id.'/public_large/*');
    $count = 0;
    $user_avatar = '/themes/users/assets/img/noartwork.jpg'; 

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $count++;
        if ($count > 0 && is_file($file)) { 
            $user_avatar = $file;
        } 
    }
?>   
<div class="user-img" style="background-image:url('<?php echo site_url($user_avatar); ?>');"></div>
```

When I inspect element on the image that's not displaying, if I change the single quotes `background-image:url('<?php echo site_url($user_avatar); ?>');` to double `background-image:url("<?php echo site_url($user_avatar); ?>");` it pulls through, but this is not the case if I make this change in the actual code.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried removing single quotes? like this :

```
 background-image:url(<?php echo site_url($user_avatar); ?>);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix for this. It was to do with the users file name containing a special character that I wasn't checking for e.g. `my-user's-image.jpg` breaks the code as the character needs to be escaped `my-user\'s-image.jpg`.

I amended the `foreach` to run a check as below and this is now working.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $count++;
    if ($count > 0 && is_file($file)) { 
        $user_avatar = str_replace("'", "\'", $file);
    } 
}
```

Thanks